# The universal term for the weather organization

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

What do you usually call the organization which forcasts the weather during the week days?

I know two terms:

> - **Meteorological organization** {it sounds a bit technical to me and I doubt if people normally use it when it comes to allude to a TV reporter within any studio area talking about upcomming whether status}
> - **Whether service** {The other term which sounds to be  dedicated to the US, while as far as I know, it is refering to the NWSO which stands for the American (National Whether Service Organization); although I guess the term that people often use in this sense should be just **Whether Service Organization** as a public and universal one; but still, I have my doubts in this regard!}

Please help me with my takings over these terms.

Comment: There isn't one. By which I mean each city, country, news agency, and so on, can use different terminology. There is no universal term. (Aside, simply, for *meteorologists*. And even then, there may be people involved who don't have that designation.) BTW: You typed *whether* rather than *weather* in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many organisations that forecast the weather (Note spelling of "weather"). And there are many roles within these organisations.

If you are referring to a particular organisation, you would use its *name*.

> The BBC recently switched from the Met Office to MeteoGroup for its weather forecasts.

You could say that the Met Office (full name "The Meteorological Office"), MeteoGroup and NWSO are all "meteorological organisations", "weather service organisations", "forecast providers". People don't often need to talk about such organisations in general, so the language is fairly technical.

> NHK news has always used the JMA as its forecast provider.
>
> The meteorological organisation "JMA" also provides earthquake alerts to NHK and other TV stations.

The person who reports on the weather is a "Meteorologist", a "weather forecaster", a "weather reporter", "weather presenter", or in a rather disparaging way "a weather girl" The first two suggest the person is actively involved in the forecast. A weather reporter suggests the person is presenting a forecast made by someone else. And "weather girl" should be avoided for the sexist implication, but comes from the use of young women in the role of weather presenter. The weather reporter is likely to not be part of the organisation that makes the forecast, but part of the TV station.